# Laravel query returns multiple objects instead of one

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a 'posts' table and a 'post_images' table. I'm trying to get data from both tables and also join 'users' table to it. it all works but the query returns different objects for each post image.

My AJAX code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: '/loadPosts',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}"},
    success: function(r){


        console.log(r);

        r.forEach((post)=>{

                $('.posts-div').append(` 
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                      <h5 class="card-header">
                      <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/585e4bf3cb11b227491c339a.png" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">
                      ${post.name} ${post.surname}
                      </h5>
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <p class="card-text">${post.text}</p>
                        <img src="images/${post.link}" style="width: 100%;">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                `);

        })
    }
})
```

The route:

```
Route::get('/loadPosts','UserController@loadPosts');
```

The function:

```
public function loadPosts(){

        $my_id = Auth::user()->id;

        $posts = DB::table('posts')->where('user_id','!=',$my_id)->join('post_images','posts.id','=','post_images.post_id')->join('users','posts.user_id','=','users.id')
        ->select('image','link','name','surname','text')
        ->get()
        ->toArray();

        print_r(json_encode($posts));
    }
```

This is what I get in AJAX success:

[result](https://ibb.co/9wrCSHQ)

New post has 3 images so it must be one object, not three.

Comment: you are doing a join, if  you know how joins work, you should know that if you have multiple images for a post you will have multiple elements with the same post

Comment: you need a oneToMany relationship or you could manualy convert your array to remove the duplicate posts

Comment: It appends posts for each image the post has.

Comment: It is a one to many. One post can have many images.

Comment: i mean oneToMany **laravel** relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Models and use `with()` to load relational data.

for table `posts` => `App\Post.php` and define relationship like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

for table `post_images` => `App\PostImage.php` Like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PostImage extends Model
{
    public function post()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
}
```

for table `users` => `App\User.php` Like:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
    }
}
```

Now in your `UserController > loadPosts` change the code Like:

```
public function loadPosts(){

    $my_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $posts = App::Post->with("images", "user")
                      ->where('user_id','!=', $my_id)
                      ->get()
                      ->toArray();

    print_r(json_encode($posts)); // you can see the unique posts entries along with `images` and `user` inside it.
}
```

Comment: @GrigoryVolkov let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you very much.